# Replace date with dynamic date format in given string

Tags: php

My string is given below.

```
$str = 'Hi $name. This is a reminder of your appointment at $dateformat("h:i A") on $dateformat("M d,Y").';
```

Suppose date is (coming from DB),

```
$appoinmentDate = '2019-02-02'
```

Now, I want to do following things with string

1. replace `$name` with John(name is coming from DB)
2. replace `$dateformat("h:i A")` with 08:52 AM (time is coming from DB)
3. `$dateformat("M d,Y")` should be replace with `date("M d,Y",$appoinmentDate)` and its result 
   should be Feb 02,2019 Like this

Important thing: `$dateformat("h:i A")` and `$dateformat("M d,Y")` will be dynamic it can be any possible date format

Can any one please help me to find out the solution?

Comment: Once you grab your values from DB, use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf) to form your string.

Comment: @El_Vanja My string is also coming from DB

Comment: we will have to fix some date formats. I dont really get any solution to get date when it is 01/02/2020 or 02/01/2020. How do we know which is the month and date.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Format of date is fixed which is coming from DB, only we want to format that date into specified format which is provided in string

Comment: you should store dates properly in the database as datetime, not strings. Storing dates as strings is a well known bad practice and leads to many problems. Dates are not text really. They should only get translated into a culture-specific text format when you are showing them to humans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regular expression that parses $str looking for any word starting with a $, and possibly followed by a ("...") sequence.

If there is a parentheses sequence, take all between the "" and use this as date format in a DateTime->format() call.

Finally, do 1 sprintf() with all the replacements and date/time insertions done at runtime

*EDIT*

Try this testscript :

```
<?php
//creating test string
$teststr='Hi $name. This is a reminder of your appointment at $dateformat("h:i A") on $dateformat("M d,Y").' ;

// parse all date format matches
$regex= "/[\$]dateformat\(?\"?([^\"]*)\"\)/" ;

$DTmatches=Array();

// try to match all $dateformat() occurences
if (preg_match_all($regex, $teststr, $DTmatches) )
{
   echo sprintf("Found following matches: %s \r\n", print_r($DTmatches,true));

   // replace this with your DB timestamp
   $theDT = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("UTC")) ;

   // count the occurences
   $nofOccurences = count($DTmatches[0]) ;

   // run over each occurence
   for ($i=0; $i < $nofOccurences; $i++)
      $teststr = str_replace( $DTmatches[0][$i], $theDT->format($DTmatches[1][$i]), $teststr ) ;   
} 
else
   echo "no dateformat() found" ;

echo sprintf("Replaced test string is: %s \r\n", $teststr) ;
?>
```

Comment: One strings can contains multiple "$dateformat("M d,Y")" and it can be different at every place

Comment: Preg_match() can return an array with all matches; so you can proceed with each occurrence as described.

Comment: You said the date/time comes from the DB: in what format did you store it in the DB ?

Comment: OK Nirali Kavar, I edited my response with a testscript.

Answer (score 0):

`$copy_date = 'Hi test. This is a reminder of your appointment at $dateformat("h:i A") on $dateformat("M d,Y").';`
`$str = preg_replace('/\$dateformat\(\"h:i A\"\)/', date("h:i A"), $copy_date);`
`$str1 = preg_replace('/\$dateformat\(\"...../', "", $str);`
`$str2 = preg_replace('/\"\)/', "'Your Date'", $str1);`

In the above code you can replace first date with date format and in other you can set date or text instead of  `Your date`.

If you want to replace both data then remove `date("h:i A")`.